# "This doesn't answer my question" - hostility from asker

Tags: discussion, comment

A couple of minutes ago I posted an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974826/existence-of-numbers-such-as-pi-1/974831#974831) regarding the existence and calculation of $1/\pi$. I gave an algebraic answer appealing to the axioms of a field, while other askers used analytic ideas. At this point the asker essentially reprimanded me in the comments on my inability to answer the given question. While I understand accepting another answer or even asking for clarification, I found this to be slightly hostile. What should one do in this scenario?

Comment: Is your answer not a re-hashing of the OPs starting point? He does say "...I would then ask myself what is, e.g. $1/\pi$ but, via the real number axioms, the solution of $\pi\cdot x=1$". So I would conjecture that the OP knows what you are saying, but is after a more analytical answer. That said, it is a poorly posed question, asking about "belief" in a number. So I wouldn't beat yourself up about it - I have seen worse answers to better questions!

Comment: A general remark: in such cases, it is good form to mention to the OP that you posted a question on meta about their behaviour.

Comment: Incidentally, I think it is also good form to refrain from excessive voting (meta effect) on the posts linked to from meta.

Comment: Still no mention of the present meta page on [the main site page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974826/existence-of-numbers-such-as-pi-1). Why the omission?

Comment: How do you say "This doesn't answer my question" without it sounding like a reprimand or appearing to be slightly hostile?

Comment: If he doesn't like the answer, he's within his rights to say so. You can accept (or ignore) the criticism and move on, or you can get in a big fight with someone you met on the Internet. I recommend one of the former options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an OP is not happy with an answer there are several (reasonable) courses of action, including:

- Explain that even if OP does not need, like, want your answer you leave it for whoever might be interested; or, do not even explain this and just move on. (Personally, I'd prefer the former, though, as it makes further comments by OP or others less likely.)
- Follow-up on OP's requests or suggestions.
- Remove it.

I would use the first as "default" and I think this is what you should do in this case; I can see why you do not like OP's reaction, but I do not think it is out of line either.

Comment: There are several more options, e.g., ignore the whole thing and go do something else; flag OP's comment as rude/offensive; hire a skywriter....

Comment: The list was not meant to be exhaustive, also it was only meant to include options I consider as reasonable. But I take the "ignore" in explicitly for the first point. Yet, flagging as offensive is only a (reasonable) option if the comment is offensive, which typically (and in the current case) it is not. I do not know what a skywriter it is so I cannot tell if hiring one is reasonable. However, an math SE answer is typically not as relevant as making to hire somebody related to it a reasonable option.